# Oracle Financial Cloud Rest API End Points

Tags: oracle-apps, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I have configured Oracle Financials Cloud.

Now I want to communicate with an Oracle Financials Cloud REST API.

How can we get that in Oracle cloud?

I checked all the settings, but I could not found the rest API endpoint.

Reference : https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/financials/18b/farfa/Quick_Start.html

Answer (score 0):

You get your REST endpoint in your Oracle Cloud welcome email.

If you don't have that one, you can look it up like this:

- Sign in to **My Account** (where the billing and service overview are, not the Financials cloud itself). Go to the services page.
- Click the service name to open the details page for Financials Cloud. At the top of the page, clicking the triangle to the left of Service Details:  displays the data center name, identity domain name (display name), identity domain id (internal name), subscription type (paid, trial, or prepaid), and service instance: production or test.
- By default, the Overview tile is in focus. It displays additional information about the service, including plan, service dates, subscription ID, order ID, account, CSI number, buyer, account administrators, data center, version, status, URL to the My Services application, SFTP user accounts, and **REST endpoint**.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/get-started/subscriptions-cloud/mmocs/viewing-service-details.html